# MIPS double point

Tags: mips, mips32, mips64

I'm editing this program so it will print out values in double point precision format. I was told to use two words to define the numbers in the double precision format. However, that's not working. The result I get is 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated! thanks!

```
.data
ZERO:                                        .double   0
ONE:                                         .double  1

POSITIVE_MIN_DBL:       .word   0x00000000   0x00100000   #2.2250738585072014 E -308
LARGEST:                   .word  0x000000 0x7f7fffff
POSITIVE_MIN:                      .word 0x00000000 0x00800000    # -3.4028235E38
POSITIVE_DENOR_MIN:      .word 0x00000000 0x00000001    # denormal min, +1.4E-45

NL:                 .asciiz   "\n"

.text
l.d   $f0,  ZERO
l.d   $f2,  ONE
div.d $f12, $f0,  $f0    # f12 = 0/0 = NaN  
jal   printFloat
div.d $f12, $f2,  $f0    # f12 = 2/0 = +infinity
jal   printFloat
l.d   $f12,   LARGEST
jal   printFloat
l.d   $f12,   POSITIVE_MIN
jal   printFloat
l.d    $f12,   POSITIVE_DENOR_MIN
jal   printFloat
j     exit

printFloat:
li    $v0,    2
syscall
la    $a0,  NL
li    $v0,    4
syscall
jr    $ra

exit:
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong system call.

System call 2 is `print_float`. What you want is system call 3 (`print_double`).

---

Also, I don't know how you came up with those hex values. They don't match the values in your comments anyway. For example, `-3.4028235e38` ought to be `0xC7EFFFFFE54DAFF8`, not `0x0080000000000000` (`0x0080000000000000` would be `2.8480945388892180e-306`).